# SQL Count operation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 queries using same table: total, I need to evaluate the  percentage of the result. (Postgres 9.4)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM total
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM total WHERE field1 = False
```

Example:

- Total count no filter returns 100 rows
- Total with field1 = False returns 10 rows.

I need to get the 10%, meaning the percentage meeting specific condition. 100/10
What is the best way to calculate it this condition in SQL?

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM total /
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM total WHERE field1 = False )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE 
               WHEN field1=false THEN 1 
             END) / COUNT(*)*100 AS percentage 
FROM table
```

You can use conditional aggregation using case expression

Comment: Be careful with integer division.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this as:

```
select avg(case when field = false then 100.0 else 0 end) as percentage
from total;
```

Assume `field` is not `NULL`, you can also do:

```
select avg( (not field)::int ) * 100 as percentage
from total;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `field1` column is `BOOLEN` Type,There is another cool way

you can use `SUM` function like this.

```
SELECT SUM((NOT field1)::INT) * 100/SUM(1) percentage 
FROM total
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eb9fd1/21*